# Checking Database for Active Billing Services

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, product, whmcs

I am putting together a small script that will query our billing database and report any customer accounts that have free services active (provided complimentary) but no longer have paid services on their accounts.

The idea is basically if they have Product ID a, Product ID b, or both of them active (we will say those are the free ones) but nothing else, I want to find those accounts. Should I just keep bools such as bProductA = false and bProductB = false and set them true if found, or could I possibly do this in a cleaner way?

```
<?php

    // Establish the MySQL Database Connections
    include_once("db.php");

    $clients = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM tblclients WHERE status = "Active"');
    while ($client = mysql_fetch_array($clients))
    {
        $client_id = $client["id"];

        $products = mysql_query('SELECT packageid FROM tblhosting WHERE userid = "' . $client_id . '" AND domainstatus = "Active" OR domainstatus = "Suspended"');
        while ($product = mysql_fetch_array($products))
        {
            // Check for MYSQL/DNS Products
            $product_id = $product["id"];
            $package_id = $product["packageid"];

            // MySQL Database
            if ($package_id == "999")
            {

            }

            // DNS Record
            if ($package_id == "999")
            {

            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: You have a error in your code. If you use `mysql_fetch_array($clients)`, you must use `$clients[0]`, `$clients[1]` etc. to get values. If you want to get the values of the arrays by db attributes like `$client["id"]`, you should use `$client = mysql_fetch_assoc($clients)`.

Comment: Woops, thank you. I had not actually used it yet as I had just put it together as a mockup to help focus my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do much work with databases, you'll be better off learning to think in terms of sets. SQL databases are based on sets. Any time you're tempted to

- run a query, then
- loop through the results, then
- execute *another* query to get the data you're interested in, then

you're almost certainly on the wrong track.

What you *should* be thinking about is identifying

- the set of active clients who have active free services, and
- the set of active clients who have active paid services.

(I'm not willing to bet that *every* inactive client has no free or paid services.)

You're *interested* in the clients who are members of the first set, but are not members of the second. You can get that with a single query.

Edit your question, and paste the CREATE TABLE statements if you want more help writing that query.